# how to solve error of aui radio button in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, liferay

Hello I am using `aui` radio in jsp.
But when I see output at web browser, user can select all radio button value. User should be able to select only one radio button but I can select all.
how to solve it?
kindly help me.

Here is my JSP:

```
<aui:input inlineLabel="right" name="veryhigh" type="radio" value="1" label="Very High" />
<aui:input name="high" type="radio"  label="Higher"  />
<aui:input name="neutral" type="radio"  label="Neutral"  />
<aui:input name="low" type="radio"  label="Low"  />
<aui:input name="verylow" type="radio"  label="Very Low"  />
```

What mistake have I done? Please tell me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to select values from a radio group then the "name" attribute of the radio type should be same for all the radio type in the group.
Simple ex:

```
<input type = "radio" name = "gender" value = "Male"/> 
<input type = "radio" name = "gender" value = "Female"/>
```

When you use the above lines only one of the radio button (Either Male or Female;depending on what user clicks gets selected)
If you give separate name attribute for the above code, then they are considered as separate and hence when you click on them both will get selected. This is exactly what is happening in your code.

```
<aui:input name="high" type="radio"  label="Higher"  /> and
 <input type = "radio" name = "gender" value = "Male"/>
```

both work the same way.. aui is alloy ui tag used in liferay...

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is that you have given the `name` of the radio button different, something like:

```
<aui:input inlineLabel="right" name="volume" type="radio" value="1" label="Very High" />
<aui:input name="volume" type="radio"  label="Higher"  value="higher"/>
<aui:input name="volume" type="radio"  label="Neutral"  value="neutral"/>
<aui:input name="volume" type="radio"  label="Low"  value="low"/>
<aui:input name="volume" type="radio"  label="Very Low"  value="very low"/>
```

On [W3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) you can learn more about form elements, it also has a section on radio buttons.